# Questions about specific software packages?

Tags: discussion

There are a few questions that haven't got much response:

[Recurring Profile and Bundled Item (Magento)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/recurring-profile-and-bundled-item-magento)

[What are common Media Library tools used for Kentico/Generic PHP sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/what-are-common-media-library-tools-used-for-kentico-generic-php-sites)

[Which hoster for asp.net application using BlackfishSQL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/which-hoster-for-asp-net-application-using-blackfishsql)

I'm thinking that I should offer a bounty to try to help them along, but it may be that they're so specific that nobody here knows the answer.

If it goes through bounty without any answers, do the questions just sit in the Unanswered area until they're addressed?

I guess one answer is to get more people in here :)

Comment: I love thinking out loud :)

Comment: +1 for the adding bounties idea. They **are** eclectic, I've never used them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tumbleweed is [not at all uncommon](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed). Very soon, the SE team is going to be working to help come up with more creative and site-specific ways to promote all of the new beta sites. I'd advise waiting on bounties to questions that might require what we commonly call *rare knowledge* until, as you said, the user base increases.

I worry that the auto accept feature of the bounty system might preclude the best expert from answering the question. Additionally, said expert might get the wrong impression of the site by seeing a possibly incorrect answer rewarded, even through an automated process that they might not understand.